# Summarizing data using SQL

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a problem that I am trying to solve using SQL and I needed your inputs on the approach to go about it.

This is how the input data & expected output looks like:

```
container_edits - This is the input table

container | units | status   |  move_time
-------------------------------------------------
XYZ       | 5     | Start    | 2018-01-01 00:00:15
XYZ       | 2     | Add      | 2018-01-01 00:01:10
XYZ       | 3     | Add      | 2018-01-01 00:02:00
XYZ       | null  | Complete | 2018-01-01 00:03:00
XYZ       | 5     | Start    | 2018-01-01 00:04:15
XYZ       | 3     | Add      | 2018-01-01 00:05:10
XYZ       | 4     | Add      | 2018-01-01 00:06:00
XYZ       | 5     | Add      | 2018-01-01 00:07:10
XYZ       | 6     | Add      | 2018-01-01 00:08:00
XYZ       | null  | Complete | 2018-01-01 00:09:00

Expected summarized output

container | loop_num | units | start_time          | end_time
------------------------------------------------------------------------
XYZ       | 1        |  10   | 2018-01-01 00:00:15 | 2018-01-01 00:03:00
XYZ       | 2        |  23   | 2018-01-01 00:04:15 | 2018-01-01 00:09:00
```

Essentially, I need to partition the data based on the status label, extract the minimum and maximum time within the partition and get the total number of units within that partition. I am aware of the usage of window functions and the partition by clause but I am unclear on how to apply that when I need to partition based on the value of a column ('status' in this case).

Any leads on how to go about solving this would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: tag with your dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a group using a cumulative sum of `starts` -- which is your `loop_num`  The rest is aggregation:

```
select container, loop_num, sum(units),
       min(move_time), max(move_time)
from (select ce.*,
             sum(case when status = 'Start' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by container order by move_time) as loop_num
      from container_edits ce
     ) ce
group by container, loop_num;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=692ac64b64d9f93d16013d091a4dfcec) is a db<>fiddle (it happens to use Postgres, but the syntax is standard SQL).

Comment: Thank you, Gordon!